# Struggling to access imap servers in windows 10

Tags: python, windows, timeout, imap

I am looking to connect to my Hotmail inbox and downloads mails from a client of mine, for which I built a python script to create a report.

The issue I have is that I inevitably get the following: 
[Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

With the exact (very basic) same code, a friend of mine connects without any problem. He is on Linux, I am on Windows10. I have tried to turn off the firewall, uninstalled MacAfee, created a rule to allow the inbound traffic through the ports 143 and 993 ... but nothing changes. When I run the diagnosis tool on the port 143 and 993, they appear as closed.

I am just an usual PC user with no particular training on ports, SSL, but I have looked quite hard.

Sending an email using STMP works without any problem.

Would you have a solution??

import imapclient
HOST = 'imap-mail.outlook.com'
server = imapclient.IMAPClient(HOST, use_uid=True, ssl=False)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "here's my working code, can you fix my computer?" is not a programming question, it's a "fix my computer" question, and off-topic for a programming site.

Comment: But still, Windows 10 firewall allows outbound traffic by default. A rule for inbound traffic shouldn't matter, you are connecting outbound, not running an IMAP server for people to connect in to. I can't connect to `imap-mail.outlook.com` on port 143 from Win 10 *or* Linux, and this Microsoft article suggests it doesn't listen on that port: https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Add-your-Outlook-com-account-to-another-mail-app-73f3b178-0009-41ae-aab1-87b80fa94970 only on 993, for SSL, so try with `ssl=True`